# What's the best way to add jQuery to Underscores (_s) WordPress theme?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

This might seem like a basic thing, but I'm unsure on **how to add jQuery** (using the CDN) **into the** [**Underscores**](http://underscores.me/) **WordPress starter theme**. I did some searching but didn't really find anything, so I was hoping someone here could have an answer for me?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The best method is to use the Wordpress function [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) in your Underscores created theme `functions.php` file.

Find the function `<THEME_NAME>_scripts` (where `<THEME_NAME>` is your theme name when generated from Underscores website) and prepend the code below, under `<THEME_NAME>_scripts` function (before any other `wp_enqueue_script`)

```
// deregister default jQuery included with Wordpress
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );

$jquery_cdn = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js';
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', $jquery_cdn, array(), '3.4.1', true );
```

Answer (score 2):

Underscores doesn't enque any javascript which rely on jquery. So a default install will not load the default jquery in WordPress without it being set as a dependency when enqueing a javascript file with `wp_enqueue_script`.

An example of loading bootstrap into underscore and loading jquery from WordPress is

`wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'),'v3',true);`

You can do the same with a jquery file from a CDN registered in WordPress

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet in either your *header.php* or *footer.php*:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This uses the Google hosted jQuery.

**Note:** WordPress ships with jQuery so if you are using Underscores as a WordPress theme then jQuery will be already enqueued.

**Ref:** https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery